# Can a normal square grid be applied to a sphere?

Tags: general-topology, polygons

I've been reading a little bit about toruses and spheres, but I am new to topology.  In my reading I came across a discussion of whether a square grid could be represented on a sphere without a "singularity" of vertices. (This is in the context of cellular movement in a grid with a toroidal topology.)

There was an answer that suggested that "[You can in fact have a normal square grid which has a spherical topology instead of toroidal. The way to do it is to use the fundamental polygon.](https://hero.handmade.network/forums/code-discussion/t/310-movement_on_spherical_vs_toroidal_tile_map#1971)"

I liked that answer very much because it led me to Riemann, who I've been wanting to learn more about, but is this answer correct?  Is the idea worth pursuing?

Comment: I'm fairly certain you cannot; it would violate Euler's formula ($V-E+F=2$).

Comment: (Well, that assumes every vertex must be adjacent to four squares, which is true on a usual square grid. If you're willing to have 8 exceptions, then you could take a cube—with each side subdivided into smaller squares if you want—and project it onto the surface of your sphere.)

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger thanks for commenting!  Can't have any exceptions in this model.  For human users (as opposed to automata) we'll likely cheat and make the grid appear as if were on a sphere of greatly expanded size, for navigation purposes, and output a regular grid in that fashion, but the underlying topological question has been bugging me ;)